# How to parse a date with 24h time using joda?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

How can I tell `joda-time` to automatically detect 24h Hour strings and parse them accordingly?

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDDhhmm").parseDateTime("201410171500");
```

Results in:

```
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "201410171500": Value 50 for clockhourOfHalfday must be in the range [1,12]
    at org.joda.time.field.FieldUtils.verifyValueBounds(FieldUtils.java:234)
    at org.joda.time.field.ZeroIsMaxDateTimeField.set(ZeroIsMaxDateTimeField.java:86)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket$SavedField.set(DateTimeParserBucket.java:568)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:447)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:411)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:882)
```

By the way, which is strange: the following works without an error:

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDDHH").parseDateTime("2014101715");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is case sensitive:

Uppercase D is Day of yeas and can have 3 digits and lowercase "h" is 12 hours.

So you have to change your pattern to:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm").parseDateTime("201410171500");
```

From the [documentaion](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

> D       day of year                  number        189
>
> d       day of month                 number        10
>
> h       clockhour of halfday (1~12)  number        12
>
> H       hour of day (0~23)           number        0

Answer (score 5):

You need to read the [documentation for pattern characters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) very carefully:

- You want `yyyy` rather than `YYYY`, as you want regular calendar years rather than year-of-era. (Not likely to be significant in Joda Time, but if you port the code to use `SimpleDateFormat`, `YYYY` would mean week-year, which you really don't want.)
- You want `HH` rather than `hh` for 24-hour clock
- You want `dd` rather than `DD` for day-of-month (you don't want day-of-year)

So:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm").parseDateTime("201410171500");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDDHHmm")
```

because h -> clockhour of halfday (1~12)

Reference - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html